# How do I check if there is a duplicate file in a folder, without comparing file names using glob/listdir/etc..?

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, file, file-io

I have a folder that contains several images, the directory structure looks like this:

```
./images/
./images/1.png
./images/2.png
./images/3.png
./images/4.png
./images/{n}.png
```

These images have been downloaded and saved using the [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) and [fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) modules by a script called `update.js`.

Each file is named after the length of items in the folder (**I.E:** length + 1).

The `update.js` script downloads (and saves) each image, regardless of whether or not it exists.

I can get around this by deleting the `images` folder but this is a waste of resources.

What's the most efficient way to prevent this behaviour?

**NOTE:** I can't use a simple file name check since, the names are indexes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can issue a HTTP head request for each file and get its headers.  Then you can see how big the target file is and avoid re-downloading it if the size matches exactly.

This isn’t ideal though as different files may have the same size.

Some servers give you a content md5 which would probably be the best.  The md5 is unlikely to match between any two files you have unless your use case is very large.

You would be better served by just working to fix the script though so it store proper metadata, all this is quite hacky :).  You can store the real file names and modified timestamps as another file in a sibling directory and be fairly sure it won’t affect anything.  Then you can just check those before doing a download.

Comment: Thanks, I have no idea as to why I haven't thought of this! I've implemented a basic [md5](https://www.npmjs.com/package/md5) hash checker and in all test cases, it's successfully prevented the script from downloading duplicate files.